# Rails: Restricting to certain records when joining

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, models

Currently I'm using the following to get get all players, go into their player_stats objects, and sum their goals.

```
Player.joins(:player_stats).group('players.id').order('SUM(player_stats.goals) DESC')
```

How can I restrict it not to use all the player_stats objects, what if I only want to sum the goals of the player_stat objects that have a specific game_id?

NOTE: I'm using mySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add where to the query:

```
Player.joins(:player_stats).group(:id).where("player_stats.game_id = ?", game_id).order("SUM(player_stats.goals) DESC")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a where clause to the query:

```
Player.joins(:player_stats)
      # you can actually pass a model as well.
      .where(player_stats: { game: game_id }) 
      .group('players.id')
      .order('SUM(player_stats.goals) DESC')
```

When you pass a hash to `.where` rails will create where conditions for the association. Its actually smart enough to use the association so you can do:

```
class Player
  belongs_to :hometown
end

Player.joins(:hometown)
      .where(hometown: { name: 'Brooklyn' })
```

and rails will query `WHERE hometowns.name = 'Brooklyn'` instead of `hometown.name`.

Because of this its generally preferable over using string conditions.